# xampp, mysql cuando le doy a iniciar se vuelve a pagar

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Este es el error

```
 23:05:29  [mysql]  Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
 23:05:29  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
 23:05:29  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
 23:05:29  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
 23:05:29  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
 23:05:29  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
 23:05:29  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums
```

He intentado hacer lo que pone en este enlace borrando da mysql data diferentes archivos pero me sigue parando al intentar inicar el mysql
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly

Que puedo hacer?

Aña el log

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 171
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-03-31 17:04:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200331 17:04:52
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-01 18:04:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-01 18:04:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-01 18:04:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-01 18:04:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-01 18:04:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-01 18:04:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-04-01 18:04:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-01 18:04:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=304232
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 304241; transaction id 197
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200401 18:04:41
2020-04-01 18:04:41 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: Revisaste si el puerto de MySQL es usado por otro programa?

Comment: Si, lo he revisado pero me dice ese error

Answer (score 0):

Deberias en primera instancia revisar cada una de las sugerencias.
"This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies," <- Si es un puerto bloqueado es simple, vas al firewall habilitas el puerto que te indique, usualmente es el **3306**.

"Press the Logs button to view error logs and check" "the Windows Event Viewer for more clues" <--- Esto es clave, revisa el log del errores del mysql. Depende del sistema operativo donde lo encontras. Si estas en widnows y con xampp dentro de xampp / mysql / data /

Comment: yo lo que hago es ir a services el del xamp y ejectuto el mysql80, no se muy buen lo de habiliar el firewall soy un novato en esto.

Answer (score 0):

Son las ips y puertos que esta usando xampp, que los tienes mal definidos. Debes entrar al control de xampp y mirar los puertos y ips en apache y mysql. Posiblemente estén usando ips que no hacen referencia a tu conexión, al igual que los puertos.